# How to get position of selected node from parent node in Xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, dom

```
string html = "<table><tr><td>xyz</td><td>abc</td><td>mno</td></tr></table>"
HtmlDocument res = new HtmlDocument();
res.LoadHtml(html);
res.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/td[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'mno')]")
```

The above code gives me `td node` which have `mno` innerText..
Now I want to know the position of `this` node from its parent node `tr`

How Can I get it???
Please Help me and Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the position this way :

```
var pos = res.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
                "//table/tr/td[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'mno')]/preceding-sibling::*"
                ).Count + 1;
```

Above code selects all preceding element in the same parent of selected `<td>` element, then get count of those returned elements plus one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//table/tr/td[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'mno')]/count(preceding-sibling::td) + 1
```